# Invert last bit

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation, bit

How can I invert the last bit in an `int`?

```
int a = 11;
System.out.print(a + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(a)) //11 1011

int b = invertLastBit(a);
System.out.print(b + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(b)); //10 1010
```

I wrote this:

```
static int invertLastBit(int i)
{
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    if (s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '0'){
        s = s.substring(0,s.length() - 1);
        s = s+"1";
    }else if (s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '1') {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
        s = s + "0";
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
}
```

But how should I rewrite `invertLastBit()` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use bitwise XOR :

```
int x = 5; // 101
x = x ^ 1; // 100
```

Using your original example :

```
int a = 11;
System.out.println (a + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(a)); //11 1011

int b = a^1;
System.out.println (b + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(b)); //10 1010
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't even have to worry about converting to binary.

If the number if odd, the last bit has to be one, thus, subtract 1 from the number.

Otherwise, if the number is even, the last bit has to be 0, add 1 to the number.

That's all.

```
static int invertLastBit(int i){
   if(i % 2 != 0) { //thanks harold
       return i - 1;
   } else {
       return i + 1;
   }
}
```

It is not difficult to reason about why this works.

Comment: I am ashamed of my question. This is obvious. Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't work for negative `i`, because `-1 % 2 == -1`. It would work if you used the test `(i & 1) == 1` or `i % 2 != 0`

Comment: I need use only positive i :) Thanks for the remark.